# How to add Python Selenium Script in Android Studio Project

Tags: python, android, selenium, web-scraping, chaquopy

I have a Python Script to get data from website and I want to add that script in Android Studio Project. For doing this I want to use [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/index.html). But I don't know how to handle the webdriver and run that selenium code. Can anyone know how to do that.

Comment: Best is to move all of it on a server and create a REST API to start script and execute action. I doubt if selenium webdriver will even work on a android phone

Comment: Yes that's a way but if it run direct in app i don't need any web server.